# Почему когда я удаляю элемент из массива, длина массива не уменьшается?

Tags: javascript

```
var i = ['kkasd', 'asdad', 'ddasda']

delete i[2];

console.log(i.length)
```

Comment: потому что элемент становится undefined

Comment: удалять надо через splice

Comment: Удалить последний элемент в массиве (array.pop())

Comment: Вам нужно использовать splice вместо delete для удаления элементов в массиве. Потому, что использование delete не меняет длину массива.

Comment: Читать нужно [документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#deleting_array_elements)

Comment: Меня интересует вопрос: А пытались ли вы вывести в консоль не длину, а сам массив? Если да, то вы сразу должны были увидеть пустой слот в массиве и вы бы задались не вопросом о длине массива, а о том хотябы что значит пустой слот? Не знаю что у вас, но лично у меня гугл по запросу "js пустой слот в массиве" выдаёт очень много полезной инфы, в том числе и где уже обсуждалось, что при удалении через `delete` появятся пустые слоты

Comment: то, что delete не меняет длину массива, автор и сам понял. Вопрос как раз и есть - почему?

Answer (score 2):

Как уже другие участники отметили `delete` лишь заменяет значение на `undefined`, вы можете убедиться в этом на текущем примере:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3]
console.log(arr)
delete arr[1] // Удаляем второй элемент массива
console.log(arr)
```

И конечно, чтобы удалить элемент массива, вы можете использовать метод [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) который вызывает мутацию или же вы можете использовать метод [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), который **не** вызывает мутации массива, тут уже сами смотрите по своей задаче.

Пример удаления элемента массива используя `slice`:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3]

console.log(arr)

arr = arr.slice(0, 1).concat(arr.slice(-1)) // Убираем элемент массива

console.log(arr)
```